# Angularjs FaceBook LIke button

Tags: facebook, angularjs

I am having an angular app in which for each image i want to have a Face book like button.
How can i integrate with Facebook API. also when the user clicks on like button of Facebook image i want to increment the like count. Should i use a static counter or can i get the return value from Facebook
It will be helpful if someone provides me few links for face book likes integration to Angular App.

Thanks

Comment: Can you accept the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

There is very nice module for angular-facebook.Take a look

https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb

You could do something like this using it.

```
<div class="fb-like" onrender="fbLikeRendered()"
  data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" 
  data-layout="standard" 
  data-action="like" 
  data-show-faces="true" 
  data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: I've not been able to get this module to work. It's probably an issue with my implementation, but I'm trying to inject the `$facebookProvider` service into the `app.config()` function like this: `app.config ([ '$facebookProvider', function( $facebookProvider )] );` and my console screams, saying it doesn't know what `$facebookProvider` is. Do you have an example using this method?

Answer (score 3):

I recently created some simple directives for Facebook Like and some other social sharing buttons, you can see a working demo and full details at http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/08/01/AngularJS-directives-for-social-sharing-buttons-Facebook-Like-GooglePlus-Twitter-and-Pinterest.aspx

Here is the code for the Facebook Like directive from the post:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('fbLike', [
      '$window', '$rootScope', function ($window, $rootScope) {
          return {
              restrict: 'A',
              link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                  if (!$window.FB) {
                      // Load Facebook SDK
                      $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function () {
                          $window.FB.init({
                              appId: $rootScope.facebookAppId,
                              xfbml: true,
                              version: 'v2.0'
                          });
                          renderLikeButton();
                      });
                  } else {
                      renderLikeButton();
                  }

                  function renderLikeButton() {
                      element.html('<div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>');
                      $window.FB.XFBML.parse(element.parent()[0]);
                  }
              }
          };
      }
  ]);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair point, I've just added the code sample for the fb like button

Comment: Really nice one.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you tell me how to resize the fb Like button (give a large size) ? Thanks in advance.